# How to set up react-qr-reader to show scan window in iPhone?

Tags: ios, reactjs, qr-code, react-qr-code

Using `react-qr-reader` library in my React / Next.js app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader

Found no relevant options for `constraints` in docs. Maybe it is a sideeffect with latest iOS it does not show scan window?

Initiating `QrReader`  like this:

```
<QrReader onResult={scanResult} constraints={{facingMode: 'environment'}} />
```

But camera scan window does not appear, only that small red icon indicate, I started to open it. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style={{ width: '100%' }}`, as in the example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader

Comment: Seems that documentation is outdated, I got this error: `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & QrReaderProps'.`

Comment: I tried `videoStyle={{ width: '100%' }}` without no luck.